# Hide table rows until search(filterBy) is done

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js(currently v.1.x, will update shortly), and I want a table of table rows containing some data. I'm using a Vue.js-component to filter the table rows with `filterBy`, but I want the table rows to be hidden before any search/filter is done.

Could anybody please help me with this? Should I place some kind of event listener somewhere? Where's the best place to put it?

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m7sgaron/863/

```js
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    data: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String
  },
  data: function () {
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function (key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power'],
    gridData: [
      { name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity },
      { name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000 },
      { name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000 },
      { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid #42b983;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

th {
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.66);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -user-select: none;
}

td {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

th, td {
  min-width: 120px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th.active {
  color: #fff;
}

th.active .arrow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.66;
}

.arrow.asc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
}

.arrow.dsc {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}

#search {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.24/vue.js"></script>
<!-- component template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="
        entry in data
        | filterBy filterKey
        | orderBy sortKey sortOrders[sortKey]">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<!-- demo root element -->
<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid
    :data="gridData"
    :columns="gridColumns"
    :filter-key="searchQuery">
  </demo-grid>
</div>
```

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @BelminBedak Exactly like that, add as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution!

Comment: I've deleted comment because I tought I missunderstand your needs, also I see you put answer already.

Comment: @BelminBedak write the answer anyway, and I'll delete mine, and I'll mark yours as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be using conditional directive such as `v-show` or `v-if` on `tr`.The expression would check does `searchQuery` has some length.

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-show="filterKey.length" v-for="
        entry in data
        | filterBy filterKey
        | orderBy sortKey sortOrders[sortKey]">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zp0m0om6/2/